# Structure program compiles without error, but no result in console window?

Tags: c

Hi friends following practice program getting compiled with zero errors but output is not showing in console window...i think there is something which i am missing ...please guide me...thanks!

```
struct card{

       char *face;
       char *suit;

       }aCard,deck[52], *cardPtr;

int main()
{
    struct card aCard;  //define one struct card Variable

   struct card *cardPtr; //define a pointer to  structure card

   cardPtr = &aCard;

   printf("%s\n %s\n",cardPtr->face, cardPtr->suit);

   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What do you expect that to print?

Answer (score 0):

`cardPtr->face` and `cardPtr->suit` are uninitialized. Hence, undefined behaviour. Allocate memory, and assign values before printing.

**EDIT**

```
cardPtr->face = malloc(n * sizeof(char));
```

where n is the number of characters that the memory block can hold. You will still have to put something in this char array before printing it.

Comment: Can you please guide me to how to allocate memory...i have tried as cardPTr = malloc(sizeof(stuct card)*10); ..but it throws error..please guide me

Answer (score 0):

You haven't assigned anything to `aCard`. Assign values to `aCard` and then assign it to `cardPtr`.

```
aCard.face="Hello";
aCard.suit="world";
cardPtr = &aCard;
```

Now you can see the values getting printed.

Comment: Thanks friends ....with your help i understood my mistakes ... great full to all you guys...thanks

Comment: @studyembedded , if you find a satisfactory answer that you think solved your problem partially/fully , then you accept the answer , and if possible , upvote the answer , that is a way of saying thanks here....